# Python regex pull first capitalized word or first and second words if both are capitalized

Tags: python, regex

The current regex formula I have implemented is only able to extract the first two capitalized words for a given string. I want to be able to extract just the first word in a string if the second word is not capitalized.

Here are some examples:

```
s = 'Smith John went to ss for Jones.'
s = 'Jones, Greg went to 2b for Smith.'
s = 'Doe went to ss for Jones.'
```

Essentially, I just want regex to output the following:

```
'Smith John'
'Jones, Greg'
'Doe'
```

The current regex formula I have is as follows, except it will not capture the Doe example:

```
new = re.findall(r'([A-Z][\w-]*(?:\s+[A-Z][\w-]*)+)', s)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regex is overkill. `str.isupper()` works quite well:

```
In [11]: def getName(s):
    ...:     first, second = s.split()[:2]
    ...:     if first[0].isupper():
    ...:         if second[0].isupper():
    ...:             return ' '.join([first, second])
    ...:         return first
    ...:
```

This gives:

```
In [12]: getName('Smith John went to ss for Jones.')
Out[12]: 'Smith John'

In [13]: getName('Jones, Greg went to 2b for Smith.')
Out[13]: 'Jones, Greg'

In [14]: getName('Doe went to ss for Jones.')
Out[14]: 'Doe'
```

Add in a couple of checks so that it doesn't error out when your string only has a single word, and you're good to go.

---

If you're bent on using regex, you can use a pattern like this:

```
In [36]: pattern = re.compile(r'([A-Z].*? ){1,2}')

In [37]: pattern.match('Smith John went to ss for Jones.').group(0).rstrip()
Out[37]: 'Smith John'

In [38]: pattern.match('Doe went to ss for Jones.').group(0).rstrip()
Out[38]: 'Doe'
```

`r'([A-Z].*? ){1,2}'` will match the first, optionally the second, if they're capitalised.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the very clear answer! Works like a charm, definitely over-thought this one...

Comment: @RickAhlf Glad I could help. Have also added a regex solution as a bonus. Thanks :)

Comment: Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
print re.match(r'([A-Z].*?(?:[, ]+)){1,}',s).group()
```

Comment: Care to add additional background information explaining what you have done ? Otherwise you risk the answer being deleted.